# Add items to a vector recursively

Tags: c++, recursion, vector

I'm attempting to create a recursive function that outputs a vector of strings that contains all possible word combinations (while retaining order of letters) of a given string. Basically, the foundation of an auto-correct typing program, which produces effects similar that of the iPhone.

```
vector<string> allPossibleWords(string str, vector<vector<char> > & adjacentKeys)
{
  vector<string> words;

  cout << str << endl;

  if (str.length() == 0)
  {
    return words;
  }

  char firstLetter = str[0];
  string restOf = str.substr(1, str.length() - 1);
  int position = position_in_vector(firstLetter);

  for (int i = 0; i < adjacentKeys[position].size(); i++) 
  {
    string temp(1, adjacentKeys[position][i]);
    words.push_back(temp);
  }

  //allPossibleWords(restOf, adjacentKeys);
}

int position_in_vector(char letter)
{
  return (letter % 97);
}
```

For instance, if str is "yp", the output should be a vector containing the values {"yp", "tp", "gp", "hp", "up", "yo", "to", "go", "ho", "uo", "yl", "tl", "gl", "hl", "ul"}. If str is "y", the output should be a vector containing the values {"y", "t", "g", "h", "u"}.

The 26 vectors stored in adjacentKeys contain the letters adjacent to the letter that is stored in the first position of the vector.

```
a   qwsz
b   vghjn
c   xdfgv
d   zserfcx
//and so on
```

I am stuck with this function, and can't figure out how to recursively build this vector.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Could you give more examples? I don't understand why "y" should map to {"y", "t", "g", "h", "u"}. Edit: I've just realised that by "adjacent" you mean letters that are beside each other on a QWERTY keyboard? The output strings will have the same length as the input string (`str`), but where each letter has been replaced with letters that are nearby it on the keyboard?

Comment: Correct -- each letter is replaced with the letters nearby it on the keyboard, along with the original letters that are part of (str).

Comment: Quick observation: have you considered that the returned vector is going to get big very quickly. It will have worst case 8^N entries where N is the number of letters in the input string, each of which will N chars long; by the time you get to 7 letters you're looking at about 14MB!

Comment: I have thought of this, but this is a very rudimentary solution that will be built upon slowly. This recursive function is just a foundation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Update: 2130 GMT Sunday: I've significantly changed my answer. I think this works now.)

Here is a complete program. There are other changes I think I would make, but I'm trying to keep to the spirit of your initial solution. It's important to return a single empty word when `str.length()==0`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


vector<string> allPossibleWords(string str, vector<vector<char> > & adjacentKeys)
{
        vector<string> words;

        // cout << "str=" << str << endl;

        if (str.length() == 0)
        {
                words.push_back("");
                return words;
        }

        char firstLetter = str[0];
        // cout << "firstLetter=" << firstLetter << endl;
        int positionInAdjacentKeys = 0;
        while(positionInAdjacentKeys < adjacentKeys.size() && adjacentKeys.at(positionInAdjacentKeys).front() != firstLetter) {
                ++ positionInAdjacentKeys;
        }
        vector<char> & adjacent = adjacentKeys.at(positionInAdjacentKeys);

        string restOf = str.substr(1, str.length() - 1);
        // cout << firstLetter << ":" << restOf << endl;

        // int position = position_in_vector(firstLetter);

        vector<string> recursiveWords = allPossibleWords(restOf, adjacentKeys);

        for (int i = 0; i < adjacent.size(); i++)
        {
                const string temp(1, adjacent[i]);
                // cout << "  temp=" << temp << endl;
                for(vector<string>::const_iterator i = recursiveWords.begin(); i != recursiveWords.end(); i++)
                {
                        // cout << "new word=" <<  temp + *i << endl;
                        words.push_back(temp + *i);
                }
        }
        return  words;
}


int main() {
        vector<vector<char> > adj;
        vector<char> v1;
        v1.clear();
        v1.push_back('p');
        v1.push_back('o');
        v1.push_back('l');
        adj.push_back(v1);
        v1.clear();
        v1.push_back('y');
        v1.push_back('t');
        v1.push_back('g');
        v1.push_back('h');
        v1.push_back('u');
        adj.push_back(v1);
        adj.push_back(v1);

        vector<string> words = allPossibleWords("yp", adj);

        for(vector<string> :: const_iterator i = words.begin(); i != words.end(); i++) {
                cout << *i << endl;
        }
}
```

return

Comment: This method produces the vector {"yp", "p"}, instead of {"yp", "tp", "gp", "hp", "up", "yo", "to", "go", "ho", "uo", "yl", "tl", "gl", "hl", "ul"}.

The letters mapped to "y" are {"t", "g", "h", "u"} and the letters mapped to "p" are {"o", "l"}.

Comment: I've just uploaded a different answer. I tested this properly now, I should have done so the first time!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?  I haven't tested it because I don't have your `adjacentKeys` matrix.  It can probably be optimised a bit, but I don't think this approach will scale well at all.

I'd suggest attacking the problem from a different angle, perhaps storing your dictionary in some kind of [K-ary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-ary_tree), and having several pointers walking the tree, following branches based on your adjacency matrix.  This would stop the generation of invalid words (and subsequent lookups to check validity) as branches would only exist where valid words exist.

```
using namespace std;

void allPossibleWordsHelper(const string& str, 
                            string::size_type index,
                            const vector<vector<char> >& adjacentKeys, 
                            vector<string>& results)
{
    if (str.length() == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    std::string head = (index > 0) ? str.substr(0, index) : "";
    std::string tail = (index < str.length() - 1) ? str.substr(index + 1) : "";

    vector<string> possibleHeads;
    string::size_type headIndex = (str.length() - index) / 2;
    allPossibleWordsHelper(head, headIndex, adjacentKeys, possibleHeads);

    vector<string> possibleTails;
    allPossibleWordsHelper(tail, index + headIndex, adjacentKeys, possibleTails);

    int pos = str[index] - 'a';

    vector<string>::const_iterator headi;
    vector<string>::const_iterator headi_end = possibleHeads.end();

    vector<string>::const_iterator taili;
    vector<string>::const_iterator taili_end = possibleTails.end();

    vector<char>::const_iterator aki;
    vector<char>::const_iterator aki_end = adjacentKeys[pos].end();

    for(headi = possibleHeads.begin(); headi != headi_end; ++headi)
    {
        for (aki = adjacentKeys[pos].begin(); aki != aki_end; ++aki)
        {
            for (taili = possibleTails.begin(); taili != taili_end; ++taili)
            {
                string suggestedWord = *headi + *aki + *taili;

                results.push_back(suggestedWord);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of passing `results` as out-parameter, you could just pass in an output-iterator. This is much more flexible.